# Is there any guideance/sample app in Android for Video Call using PJSIP?

Tags: android, video, call, pjsip

Hi Coder Enthusiast,

I am novice in PJSIP.I want to make video calling using the PJSIP.

By googling i came to know that PJSIP do support video calling in its latest relaese.

I have taken reference of the [CsipSimple](https://github.com/r3gis3r/CSipSimple) App to make Voice calling and implemented successfully as per my requirement.

For video calling i found [this](https://github.com/jojonarte/android_PJSIPSpike) sample app for android.But this app is not working as per my expectation.

So is there any other sample app or demo that can guide me in my development.

Please let me know if you need any other info from my side to help you understand my problem in a more clear way.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I know is too late, but PJSIP provide a sample app. When you download the source code you will find the sample app in:

pjsip-apps/src/swig/java/android

You can download the PJSIP source here: http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm

You can see the sample app here too: 
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/browser/pjproject/tags/2.6/pjsip-apps/src/swig/java/android

Remember that you have to compile PJSIP with the video enabled. Just follow the Getting Started document: 
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android